# How to pass value from one view controller to another swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building an iOS app using storyboards.I have implemented google maps in my app using swift.I'm getting address value in a label.I'm facing an issue to pass that label value to another class(First view controller) written in objective c.

What is happening right now in storyboards in first view controller i have a button and on click on that modal segue perform open second view controller contain map and this map view controller contain done button to dismiss the view controller and get bact to the first view controller.

Here is storyboard image:

[image]

here is my code:

Map View Controller code in swift:

```
func reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate) { response , error in

      //Add this line
      self.addressLabel.unlock()
      if var address = response?.firstResult() {
        println("label657656558568===\(address)");

        //  self.addressLabel.text=address.valueForKey ("GMSAddress") as? NSString;
        self.addressLabel.text=address.valueForKey ("subLocality") as? NSString;

        println("label===\(self.addressLabel.text)");
        let labelHeight = self.addressLabel.intrinsicContentSize().height
        self.mapView.padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: self.topLayoutGuide.length, left: 0, bottom: labelHeight, right: 0)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25) {
             self.pinImageVerticalConstraint.constant = ((labelHeight - self.topLayoutGuide.length) * 0.5)
          self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
      }
    }
  }
@IBAction func doTap(x:UIButton) {

     self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});//This is intended to dismiss the Info sceen.
        println("pressed")

    }
```

Comment: check out this http://jamesleist.com/ios-swift-passing-data-between-viewcontrollers/

Comment: Now i'm getting i'm using custom segue instead of modal segue and getting the value of location in first view controller but now my iboutlet of label is hide in the ui and does not display the value of location,but when i print in the console there i'm getting the label value. @Edward

Comment: well, in your class you can create variable 'var yourViewController', set it in 'viewDidLoad()' to infoViewController. On button click you assign that controller to the presentViewController and after you dismiss it you can check for values. So, you will present it like this: 'self.presentViewController(yourViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)' and you can use label as yourViewController.yourLabel since, I assume, it is property of your infoViewController

Answer (score 2):

you can use [delegate protocols](https://gist.github.com/pocketkk/d4ced019a7e5086bf677) here to pass the value from MapViewController to FirstViewController. Here is the example [link](https://gist.github.com/pocketkk/d4ced019a7e5086bf677)

Comment: Now i'm getting i'm using custom segue instead of modal segue and getting the value of location in first view controller but now my iboutlet of label is hide in the ui and does not display the value of location,but when i print in the console there i'm getting the label value. @suhit

Comment: why downvote, it's one of the way to pass the values to presenting viewcontroller, it's a comman to use delegates for such purpose, please explain?

Comment: definitely useful! Thanks a lot Suhit.